# UiTableviewCell with dynamic data init not loading correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

in my cell data is loading but its is all messed up until i scroll down then if i scroll back everything format correctly. so when every i load listing which is uitableview data is messed up and as soon i start scrolling and scroll back up it gets in place and show correctly. please help.

my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for(UIView *v in [cell subviews])
    {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
UIView *CellBGView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, cell.frame.size.width-20, cell.frame.size.height-10)];
    CellBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImageView *divider = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CellBGView.frame.size.width-155,       CellBGView.frame.size.height-140, 150, 150)];
    divider.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_alpha.png"];
    [CellBGView addSubview:divider];
    ......
    return cell;
}
```

Here is out put when i open listing and before scrolling table

[image]

here is after scrolling everything gets in place

[image]

Comment: You should use a custom cell, rather than a standard one and configure the layout in your storyboard. And you really need to re-read Apple's documentation about TableViews and TableViewCells.

Comment: Why do you need to remove `UILabel` and `UIImage` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: If you are not reusing the subviews, adding subviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not right place to do so. As each time user scrolls the tableview, newer and newer allocated views will be added to cell. From your code snippet, `CellBGView` and `divider` will be allocated and added as subview each time user scrolls.

Comment: @trungduc Removing to avoid duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you.

- First, create subclass of `UITableViewCell` (For example, name it `DemoTableViewCell`)
- In `initWithStyle` method of `DemoTableViewCell`, add your images and labels to cell.
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you don't need add or remove images and labels. Just change color or set image for them.